# Fetch gives me javascript instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Fetch gives me

> text/javascript

redirectRequest() instead of the html content. I am out of ideas. Typically the solution for most people was that they were not using response.text() which is not the case for me. Here is the code example that i am using:

```
mounted() {
let url = "http://atkinsglobal.taleo.net/careersection/atk_sweden/jobdetail.ftl?lang=sv&job=SWE000036";
fetch(url)
.then(function(data) {
    return data.text();
  })
.then(function(html){
  // var parser = new DOMParser();

  // // Parse the text
  // var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

  console.log(html);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // If there is any error you will catch them here
});
```

which is giving me the result: 
[image]

I even tried another method using DOMParser which was no different. What can i do here guys? Is there a way to simulate being client side and parse the HTML from there?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is trying to do a redirect. You should be able to get it to follow the redirect for you [by adding the header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options).

```
let headers = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow' // Add this
}

fetch(url, headers)
   .then(function(response) {
       return response.text();
   })
   .then(function(html){
       console.log(html);
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error);
   });
```

Comment: The output for me was no different :/

Comment: Tried adding the same header in POSTMAN, still getting the javascript as output